# Better Russian dictionary for Android's autocorrect?

Tags: languages, dictionary

The built-in Russian dictionary is extremely small and I keep adding new words to it every day. Is there a better one anywhere on the web?

Comment: Have you tried alternative keyboard replacement apps?

Comment: I like the Google keyboard, so I think it would be easier to import a dictionary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install [User Dictionary Manager](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.usr.dict.mgr)
-(With this you can import/export/delete/edit dictionaries)

*Now after installing User Dictionary Manager Download Russian Dictionary (Ru.zip 2012) From [Here](https://onedrive.live.com/?cid=3732e80b128d016f&id=3732E80B128D016F%213584)

*Unzip Russian Dictionary File

*Import .txt file with User DictionaryManager.

> **DONE**

[Dictionary Source](http://invokeit.wordpress.com/frequency-word-lists/)

Comment: Thanks a lot! Though I couldn't find the 2013 version for Russian in the folder you've linked.

Comment: Sorry mate! It was typo. I just updated it.

Comment: Importing all 400k+ words turned out a huge mistake, so I simply limited the dictionary to 10,000 of the most common words.

Comment: You can also copy paste 1000 most used russian words from http://masterrussian.com/vocabulary/most_common_words_2.htm and import it by making .txt file of it.

Comment: Android's built-in dictionary does have most words, but it's lacking the endings variations. As in, it knows about "dog", but doesn't know that "dogs" is also correct.